# Regex pattern not working in Python script

Tags: python, regex

I need to find a specific word in the HTML of a list of pages. I'm using regex instead of BeautifulSoup, because I find it often easier.

The code is:

```
links= ['http://www-01.sil.org/iso639-3/documentation.asp?id=alr','http://www-01.sil.org/iso639-3/documentation.asp?id=ami', ...]
for link in links:
    d = requests.get(link)
    p = re.compile(r'<td valign=\"top\">Name:<\/td>\n\t+<td>\n\t+(\w+)\n\t+<\/td>')
    lang = re.search(p, d.text)
```

This is a snippet of `d.text`:

```
<div id="main">
<h1>Documentation for ISO 639 identifier: bnn</h1>
<hr style="margin-bottom: 6pt">

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top">Identifier:</td>
                <td>bnn</td>
            </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td valign="top">Name:</td>
                    <td>
                    Bunun
                    </td>
                </tr>

            <tr>
                <td valign="top">Status:</td>
                <td>Active</td>
            </tr>
```

I don't know why, but `lang` is `None`. I checked my regex pattern on regex101, and also on Sublime. I printed d.text, and the HTML is normal: if I put `d.text` in Sublime and search the same pattern, it works.
 I don't understand why but the pattern doesn't work in the script, but everywhere else... I'm using Python3. I must be doing something silly, but I don't understand what...

Comment: @PeterWood I didn't.

Comment: Can you give a small example of the data `d.text` so we can try and reproduce the problem. Make it as small as possible. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Done, hope it's enough.

Comment: @PeterWood look again :) I only reformatted the code block. The `<code>` and `</code>` are not part of the regex.

Comment: Are you certain there are no spaces in the HTML, in addition to the tabs?  Is there a reason you're explicitly looking for a specific number of tabs rather than any length of whitespace?

Comment: @BryanOakley No, and no. It's simply that I can't code well. Thanks!

Comment: @Aubrey that's great

Comment: @MarounMaroun Ah, I understand. The `<code>` tags stopped markdown interpretting the html tag in the regex, so it became visible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One should be very careful with '\n'. File lines may finish with '\n' (Linux style), with '\r' (MacOS style) or both (Windows style). In your case it's easy to correct your expression accepting `[\n\r]+` in place of `\n` and it works fine with your example links:

```
p = re.compile(r'<td valign="top">Name:</td>[\n\r]+\t+<td>[\n\r]+\t+(\w+)[\n\r]+\t+</td>')
```

However, I strongly advise against relying on any spacing structure in a document. What if they change it? It wouldn't ever be visible on site! I believe it's better to let spacing be free. Like the following:

```
p = re.compile(r'<td valign="top">Name:</td>\s*<td>\s*(\w+)\s*</td>')
```

It's also need to be noted that *valign* attribute is deprecated in HTML5 (CSS is to be used instead) and thus it may completely disappear from documents in near future.

Comment: You do not have to escape `/` in Python regex. And `"` inside a single-quoted string literal either.

Comment: Backslashes removed (sorry my C++ :) )

Answer (score 1):

```
p = re.compile(r'<td valign="top">Name:</td>\s+<td>\s+(\w+)\s+</td>')
```

as @Bryan Oakley mentioned, there are whitespaces between `<td></td>`, try `\s+` to match one or more whitespaces. `\s=[ \f\n\r\t\v]`

besides, by using raw string notation, there is no need to use backslash to indicate special forms